# When did initial-origin words (PRONOUNCED AS WORDS) start happening?

Tags: etymology, history, acronyms

Someone was just [asking](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268148/does-english-contain-any-abbreviated-words-as-a-core-part-of-its-corpus) if there were words like lol formed, before, the txtmsg era.

Of course there were - for example "laser".

**However** .. in fact what was the earliest example of this in English?

## Words pronounced as full words - but which started as initials or the initial parts of a series of words.

What is the earliest example of a word like "radar"?

Is there anything like "laser" (laser: 1960) before, let's say, the electric era?  Just a wild guess -- did this fad perhaps start with WW2?

So where and when did this begin in English, and what is the earliest example?

---

Note -- here's a somewhat related question, but the information there is utterly [useless](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33532/when-did-the-use-of-acronyms-begin). It's astounding that people can't grasp the difference between laser or lol, and, CIA or INRI.

Comment: There may be something in what you say. The earliest example of the word *acronym* - per the OED - is 1940. The one I kept thinking of, whilst reading your OP was *Radar* - *Radio detection and ranging*. Its entry in the OED dates it from 1940 too. But somehow I would be amazed if there were not pre-war examples of acronyms. The T.U.C. (Trades Unions Congress) dates from 1910 - but it is never pronounced *tuc* - always T.U.C. - perhaps for this very reason.

Comment: Beware, the German word *akronym* dates from 1921 - OED.

Comment: I sure can't think of any acronyms from, say, Jane Austen's day.  When was the first?!

Comment: I seem to remember something about "B.O." (body odour) being an early acronym (I appreciate it's not, quite, a "turned in to a conventionally spoken word" example ...)  Perhaps someone knows the timing for B.O.

Comment: Perhaps the Germans were at it first. When was FLAK invented? It stands for *Fl(ieger)a(bwehr)k(anone*, literally *air defence gun*.

Comment: I believe it's an internet MEME. Everything began with the internet.

Comment: The [NAAFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navy,_Army_and_Air_Force_Institutes#Before_NAAFI) has its origins as early as 1892. Pronounced *naffi*, it provides canteens, and small provisions shops attached to the British armed services. Anyone who has been in the services refers to it as *the naffi*. e.g. *Let's nip down to the naffi for a cup o' tea*.  What I am not clear about was whether it was referred to as *the naffi* before 1939.

Comment: I did not know that about flak.  And i have no idea when people started saying naffi.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that **etc** goes back a long way since it has its foundations in Latin. Does it count as an acronym, or merely an abbreviation?

Comment: "et cetera" is a totally normal word. (Well, pair of words.)  We happen to sometimes abbreviate it "etc." or "&c".  This is no different from, say, "Mister" often being abbreviated to "Mr."

Comment: @JoeBlow The GESTAPO (*Geheime Staatspolizei*) was formed in 1933.

Comment: POSH (port outbound starboard home) is not really an acronym, but was believed to be one as early as [1938](https://books.google.com/books?id=G7I-AQAAIAAJ&q=posh+port+starboard+home&dq=posh+port+starboard+home&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBWoVChMIzp6JiL-4xwIVCxSSCh31LguM), so they must have been fairly widespread at that time.

Comment: Following up on the references to German above, Gestapo is an acronym and dates to at least 1933. Gulag is one as well, in Russian, though I don't know when it originated. What about the possibility that acronyms originated in languages other than English and the concept picked up from there?

Comment: The *OED* date AM (morning) to 1762, although it's always been pronounced as two letters.  AD predates English.

Comment: Peter .. FANTASTIC point on posh!   (although I believe the origin is debated.)

Comment: Hi Dead.  That's fascinating about "AM", but I am interested in words (pronounced entirely as words .. like "radar") which started as acronyms.

Comment: I was going to suggest NyLon, but just like POSH [it appears the well-known story of the name is untrue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nylon#Etymology).

Comment: I would be willing to bet that the Catholic church had several, from Latin.  The thing is, *pronouncing* an acronym tends to not be documented, because what is written is the individual letters, regardless of how it's spoken.  (Certainly, beginning with the runup to WWII it became common to pronounce acronyms and abbreviations -- the military was awash in abbreviations, and GIs were always willing to play games with the nomenclature.)

Comment: May I suggest a title change to something like "When did initials start being pronounced as words?" or perhaps "When did acronyms begin to be formed from initials?" The present title looks a bit inarticulate. Worth note is that the word [initial](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=initial&searchmode=none), in the sense of the initial of a surname comes from 1600  and initialize comes from 1833 according to The Online Etymology Dictionary. You can not pronounce initials without initials so I think this information may help narrow the scope of research significantly.

Comment: Hi Tone - just click Edit if you have a specific actual suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When did the use of acronyms begin?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33532/when-did-the-use-of-acronyms-begin)—a question asked in 2011, and closed a year later. At the very least, you might want to look over the answers there for an interesting discussion of the same issues that you ask about here.

Comment: Thanks Sven - you know I already mentioned that question, I think?, but it got edited out or something.  You know, (1) all the info there is useless (2) it suffers this horrible problem that **nobody actually knows what acronym means** (including me).   **Is CIA an acronym?** or is only laser an acronym?  I have simply avoided using the term 'acronym' in this discourse, since it is useless and the word 'acronym', very very simply, has no widely agreed-upon meaning.  So, I just spell out at length "words that are pronounced as words" etc.

Comment: A lot of people are unclear about the difference between _tortoises_ and _terrapins_ —but that doesn't mean that the two entities aren't distinctly different (and well defined). The same goes **in general** for _acronyms_ and _initialisms_, and I have no trouble telling most of them apart. The only problem arise in quirky in-between cases (like the one I raise at your other question about whether acronyms are well defined: CRP, pronounced {by people hostile to it} as if it were spelled _CREEP_). There, I think, things begin to break down in an otherwise reasonably straightforward distinction.

Comment: Hi Sven - that's a fair general point (I mean about the turtles - it's turtles all the way down!) {it also makes me think of the deathless opening of *Bladerunner*...} however, observe that on this very question it did cause not inconsiderable confusion.  (For that reason, i scrubbed it from the Q.)

Comment: Suggestions for title: **"What was the first abbreviation consisting of initial letters that was pronounced as a word?"**  Or **"When did abbreviations, consisting of initial letters, start being pronounced as words?"** (*initial-origin word* makes no sense)

Comment: Last chance at 150 points (if anyone cares), there's really only one answer here that is not, let us say, interesting but somewhat offtopic.

Comment: Just to add the taint of Commerce - there's a long line of companies with initials that lend themselves to be spoken as words, deliberately or otherwise. I'm thinking FIAT, and SAAB.  I guess the *deliberate* forming of initials into a 'readable' form is another question.

Comment: 'Acronym' is ill-defined, so it is no wonder that people get confused about what it means. the strictest definition I've come across demands lower-case membership of the lexicon (radar, scuba); most people seem to choose the 'must be pronounced as a word' requirement (radar, ISA), but some people include all initialisms (radar, ISA, BBC). / There certainly are useful answers in the original.

Comment: @SvenYargs If you're still bothering people about that non-extant distinction, you can stop. ['Acronym' originally and primarily means precisely "A group of initial letters used as an abbreviation for a name or expression, each letter or part being pronounced separately; an initialism (such as ATM, TLS)"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1844). They are completely synonymous and it's a mumpsimus to pretend otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

See: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym) for a good discourse on the historical use of acronyms. I knew the Catholic church used the acronym INRI on top of the crucifix for at least 500 to 600 years. A qoute from the Wikipedia article: "Acronyms were used in Rome before the Christian era. For example, the official name for the Roman Empire, and the Republic before it, was abbreviated as SPQR (Senatus Populusque Romanus). "

Comment: Interesting 'Q' there.

Comment: Isn't there an important difference between abbreviations and acronyms? A proper acronym is an abbreviation pronounced as a [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym). Is "INRI" pronounced as "Innree", or "SPQR" as "Spucker"?

Comment: Yes, SPQR is definitely pronounced "spooker," and I've always thought of INRI as a word, though I don't think I've heard anyone use it.

Comment: Hmm, it's a great observation about the Roman **abbreviations**.  But this really **doesn't answer my question, at all**, I'm afraid.  (For example, quite simply -- was "laser" the first word that, as my question asks, "came from" an acronym?

Comment: @Joe Blow. Clearly not. The Wiki article spells it all out. *The early Christians in Rome, most of whom were Greek rather than Latin speakers, used the image of a fish as a symbol for Jesus in part because of an acronym—fish in Greek is ichthys (ΙΧΘΥΣ), which was said to stand for Ἰησοῦς Χριστός Θεοῦ Υἱός Σωτήρ (Iesous CHristos THeou hUios Soter: "Jesus Christ, God's Son, Savior"). This interpretation dates from the 2nd and 3rd centuries and is preserved in the catacombs of Rome.*

Comment: I guess you didn't completely read the Wikipedia article. It goes on to say: "**The Hebrew language has a long history of formation of acronyms pronounced as words**, stretching back many centuries. The Hebrew Bible ("Old Testament") is known as "Tanakh", an acronym composed from the Hebrew initial letters of its three major sections: Torah (five books of Moses), Nevi'im (prophets), and K'tuvim (writings). Many rabbinical figures from the Middle Ages onward are referred to in rabbinical literature by their **pronounced acronyms**..."

Comment: Terry, I'm sure you're right with the official meaning of SPQR but I prefer the version from Asterix: Sono Pazzi Questi Romani [they're crazy, these Romans]!

Comment: David, that's great! That reminds me of the backronym for perl, the programming language: Pathologically Eclectic Rubbish Lister!

Comment: Hi Terry - that's fascinating that Yiddish has made WORDS (sounded out AS WORDS, I assume that is what you mean) from acronyms, from ye olde times.  I'm really asking about English here - but that's fascinating

Comment: How about this Joe?   Amphetamine: 1930s, chemical name, a(lpha-)m(ethyl) phe(ne)t(hyl)amine

Comment: Hi Terry!  That's great -- is that about the earliest ?

Comment: Hey Joe. I'm certain it isn't. When the telegraph came out in the 1800s, they used to abbreviate everything! Time is money after all. I'm sure there were plenty of abbreviated words and terms that lent themselves to being pronounced. The navy and army would have made good use of abbreviations as well, and then would have had messages sent via telegraph! There out there...

Comment: @TerryWendt, now you've mentioned the armed forces, we have to bring in 'snafu'.

Comment: @TerryWendt: When was INRI introduced into the English language? What evidence is there for people pronouncing it as "inree" in the English language?

Comment: I'm afraid this answer simply does not address the question. The question is about words **such as laser** which are pronounced as words, but which in fact **started as initials**.  I apologise if the question was initially unclear.

Comment: Also, it would seem to be **entirely incorrect** that INRI and SPQR are ever said (then or now) as words (ie, as "inri" or "spqr").  Note that (1) they are always written as INRI or SPQR, they are never written as words.   (2) SPQR is not pronounceable.

Comment: @Margana [No, acronyms are originally and primarily initialisms and the term has nothing to do with their status as pronounceable words.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1844)

Answer (score 1):

### Edit: Updated Answer

After more research, I verified that the [OED](http://www.oed.com/) does observe the distinction between initialisms and acronyms, invited by the distinct senses (in the OED) of 'initialism' and 'acronym' (as abbreviations pronounced as individual letters in the former, and abbreviations pronounced as words in the latter), in its **Etymology** notes. I respect that distinction in this answer.

That verity enabled the simplification of research into the *earliest acronyms* appearing in the OED. In the following historical breakdown, I only include words with clear, unequivocated acronymic etymologies. Thus,

*Of words originating in English between c1000 and 1600*, no acronyms appear in the OED.

*Of words originating in English between 1600 and 1800*, the noun 'abjad' is undoubtedly an acronym. It derives from the Arabic word 'abjad' (also acronymic), denoting the Arabic alphabet: the word is an acronymic abbreviation formed from the initial letters of the names of the first four letters of the Arabic alphabet. The first textual evidence of its use appeared in 1793:

> 1793   C. F. Greville Brit. India Analyzed I. 87   The first letter of the month Ahmudee is Alif, which, in the Abjud, stands for 1.

(op. cit.)

Thus, 'abjad' has the honor of being the earliest acronym in English documented by the OED. No other serious contenders for the earliest acronym were to be found in that period (1600-1800).

Being curious, I continued the exercise.

*Of words originating between 1800-1900*, there are several acronyms. In historical order, those are 'Tanach' (1835), 'SCOTUS' (1879), 'OUDS' (1885), 'AWOL' (1894), and 'POTUS' (1895).

*A further search for acronymic words originating between 1900-2000* returned 287 results. I did not visit each entry (as I did for the earlier, more managable quantities of results) to verify that the reference to 'acronym' in the **Etymology** was clear and unequivocal, and to verify the date of the earliest acronymic use of the word.

### Original answer

The question invites argument: "the earliest example" in the question could resolve as the date the abbreviation was first pronounced as a word, or the first recorded appearance of the abbreviation later to be pronounced as a word. If the former, how is that date to be documented?

Anyway, I'll throw a word into the ring:

> AWOL, n. and adj.
>
> ...
>
> 1894   Rep. National Home for Disabled Volunteer Soldiers in Misc. Documents House of Representatives 1894-5 (1895) 431   November 25: Patient left the ward this date without leave. December 5: Patient returned from A. W. O. L.

(op. cit.)

Note that the OED distinguishs 'acronym' and 'initialism' on the basis of whether or not each letter or part is pronounced separately: for *initialisms* each letter or part is pronounced separately; *acronyms*, on the other hand, may have each letter or part pronounced separately **or** the whole may be pronounced as a single word.

Thus, my rather shaky assumption is that where the OED gives an etymology as "acronym" or "initialism", it maintains that distinction. This assumption is supported by the etymology given for 'awol':

> **Etymology:** As noun, acronym < the initial letters of absence without leave ....
>
> In early use sometimes an *initialism*; compare quot. 1949 at sense B. 2, and also:
>
> 1921   Outing June 137/1, I was surprised to find one day that unless I left the following morning to rejoin my regiment I would be an ‘a-w-o-l’.
>
> 1957   B. Evans & C. Evans Dict. Contemp. Amer. Usage 9/2   awol..in World War I..was pronounced as four letters; in World War II, it was pronounced as a word.

(op. cit., italics mine)

Rather than helping, however, the OED's distinction leaves the question of *when* an initialism first becomes an acronym up in the air. Presumably, the question is unresolved because documentation will rarely answer it, and because the question is extraneous to the OED's primary concern with when the acronym/initialism was first recognizably used as a noun (adjective, whatever) as documented in textual records.

For somewhat hesitant and possibly unreliable support of my claim that awol was the first or among the first acronyms, as well as a disquisition emphasizing the distinction between acronyms and initialisms, see ["Acronyms that became words"](http://www.runitbyfred.com/acronym-to-word/).

Comment: AWOL today is often said as "a-double-u-oh-ell", or, as "Aywhol".  how was it said then?

Comment: BTW awol is a great suggestion. I have no idea though when it was first pronounced "Aywhol".

Comment: @JoeBlow, that is a tough question. One of the quotations I included from the OED, itself from the 1957 Dictionary of Contemporary American Usage, says it was pronounced with each letter during WWI and as one word during WWII. We're left to assume the change was sometime between the wars. I'm not sure I believe the source, anyhow; in order to verify the claim from that source, I'd have to find the book and see what else they have to say, or do some stunning research that's beyond my means.

Comment: @JoeBlow, I'm familiar with the windfucker, aka windhover, from a distant course on GM Hopkins' poetry (["The Windhover"](http://www.bartleby.com/122/12.html), "...dapple-dawn-drawn Falcon...") during which the professor huhhed his way through the observation that the bird was also known as the windfucker. That professor was something of a frustrated dramatist.

Comment: The bottom line there is then, **as best you know, "aywhol" became a 'pronounced word' around 1930**. If that's the best we know, perhaps edit it in to the answer?  If we do not know that, and in fact have no clue at all when "aywhol" came to be said like that ... well then that's that.

Comment: @JoeBlow, I'm not willing to accept a partial quote from an uncertain source as the best I (or we) know. The etymology in the OED also says "In early use *sometimes* an initialism....", which to me implies that in early use it was *sometimes* an acronym. The earliest use in the textual record was 1894, so that's the earliest recorded possibility of use as an acronym: presumably, however, the expression had been in use prior to becoming part of the textual record. So, as best I know, awol was used as an acronym sometime **before** 1894.

Comment: @JoeBlow The OED has quotations from 1918 and 1919 where it's written as "awol" and "awols" so possibly pronounced as a word. They're also under a colloquial, chiefly military sense. Earlier ones are all "A. W. O. L." under military senses.

Comment: Hugo - very interesting!

Comment: @Joe Blow: the etymology *windstriker* for *windfucker* makes no sense at all, knowing the habits of the kestrel. But *fuck* also meant *mock* in Dutch, and *windmocker* is a very apt name for the kestrel, which is now called the *windhover.* Whoever told you that *windfucker* meant *windstriker* and that the bird was now called a *windstriker* did not know what the f*** they were talking about. *Windstriker* is not even in the OED.

Comment: @PeterShor, where did the 'windfooler' in your original comment come from? Any basis in fact?

Comment: @JEL: I looked up the etymology of *fuck*, and the OED says it was akin to a Dutch word that originally meant *mock, fool, strike*. The term *windstriker* doesn't make any sense as a term for the kestrel, whose claim to fame is one of the very few birds that hovers in place, disregarding the wind. Both *windfooler* and *windmocker* make sense, though. I revised my comment to *mock*, which is an earlier sense than *fool*, according to the OED.

Comment: hi Peter!  if you know a lot about birds, thats great - I don't.  no twitcher here! this is now one of those entirely tangential discussions

Comment: enjoy that bounty!

Comment: @Joe Blow ... and now, I really would like to know which meaning of *fuck* gave rise to *windfucker*. I would guess *mock* (somehow imported from the Dutch), but I don't think there'll be any evidence in the corpus. The first meaning of *fuck* the OED attests in English is the sexual one.

Comment: Hey Peter.  I assumed it was the sense, the kestrel is "mating with" the wind - it seems pretty obvious I guess. The bird adopts a similar or identical position a male bird does during mating.

Comment: Of course, who knows.

Comment: Nope. No idea what you were looking at [but the actual *OED* entry for 'acronym' lists it primarily as "A group of initial letters used as an abbreviation for a name or expression, each letter or part being pronounced separately; an initialism (such as ATM, TLS)."](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1844)

Comment: @lly, I'll make one stab at this, then drop it. I'm not optimistic about your ability to grasp the nuances (because your comment is disputacious--"No idea what you were looking at but the actual etc."--rather than collaborative). *OED* is a historical dictionary (among other things). The first definition given is historically "primary"; others given are later developments. Contrast the definition of 'initialism': "...each letter or part being pronounced separately (contrasted with acronym n.)". And see the detailed research into the *use* of 'acronym' in *OED* etymologies shown in the answer.

Comment: @lly, just to be clear, 'acronym' and 'initialism' have been and continue to be used (albeit carelessly) interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

An acronym is an abbreviation (or intialism) that's pronounced as a word. They're a relatively modern invention; there are a few earlier examples, but their use really took off during WWII.

### INRI?

INRI may be old, but when was INRI introduced into the English language? What evidence is there for people pronouncing it as "inree" in the English language?

---

### WWI

In Douglas Harper's rebuke, '["shit" is not an acronym](http://www.etymonline.com/baloney.php)', he writes that acronyms are very modern inventions. They were found in World War I, but still weren't the preferred way of abbreviation. Their use really took off and became common during World War II, and really accelerated during the cold war and US space programme.

He also notes the use of *acrostics*, a poem or puzzle such as *cabal*, where the first initial of an existing word is made of other significant words. However, Harper argues this wordplay had been around for centuries and they aren't really acronyms: the root word already existed and no-one was pretending the initials were the source.

Read the interesting article for more, here's a brief snippet:

> Acronyms didn't becom a common method of word formation in English until World War II. The word acronym itself wasn't coined until 1943. The lack of a need for such a word suggests the degree to which acronyms previously were not a part of daily life. Their use accelerated with the U.S. space program and the Cold War, and by the time a "Dictionary of Acronyms, Initialisms and Abbreviations" was published in 1960 it had 12,000 entries.
>
> ...
>
> So acronyms in English are on the whole a 20th century phenomenon. Among those with pre-1900 origins are A.D. and B.C. (both Latin) and P.D.Q. (1870s). The word OK (c.1839) is another rare exception (if the most accepted theory of its origins is the right one), as is n.g. for "no good" (1838). And note how these initialisms, even after more than 170 years, are still "felt" as abbreviations, pronounced as distinct letters, and require no elaborate Internet stories.

---

### POTUS & SCOTUS

There are at least a couple of acronyms pronounced as words which predate World War I: POTUS (President of the United States) and SCOTUS (Supreme Court of the United States), from the [Phillips Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phillips_Code) used "for the rapid transmission of press reports by telegraph", are from [1895](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-pot1.htm) and perhaps [1879](http://books.google.com/books?id=zw9LAAAAYAAJ&q=SCOTUS+%22Supreme+Court+of+the+United+States%22&dq=SCOTUS+%22Supreme+Court+of+the+United+States%22&hl=en&ei=x8fMTpPyMcHChAfIk7DeDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA). I'd guess that they weren't originally pronounced as words, but they [are](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/POTUS) [now](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/SCOTUS).

Comment: Does anyone know whether the Soviet state security agency whose Western initial were OGPU (created in 1922, and the predecessor of the NKVD and (even later) the KGB was pronounced in the west as "O-G-P-U" or as _ogpu_? Its parent agency was the GPU, so English speakers may have been inclined toward the initialism pronunciation at first, but I believe that _ogpu_ was used at a certain point before the agency's reinvention as NKVD in 1934.

Comment: Before the 1930s POTUS and SCOTUS may only have been pronounced as words by telegraph operators. Consider the following joke from the *Commercial Telegraphers' Journal* from 1918, which at the very least shows that these acronyms were not widely used. *The sender complying with the request, ran through a bunch of "code" and wound up with "potus." The following conversation took place: "Bk. What's potus?" "President of the United States." "Bk. No; Wilson" is."*

Answer (score -1):

I think @PaulDrye had the right instinct in his comment. As a Russian student, I strongly associate initialisms with Communist-era propaganda; they were the bread and butter of the political vocabulary of the Soviet Union.

However, [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=FddBAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA261&lpg=PA261&dq=%22the%20abbreviations%20formed%20by%20initials,%20because%20of%20their%20frequent%22&source=bl&ots=70Q6CxwI0J&sig=AKztvoczpxz1TwsG4bWeM5io78E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSzr_7k93NAhVJkx4KHUbwC7oQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20abbreviations%20formed%20by%20initials%2C%20because%20of%20their%20frequent%22&f=false) interesting source suggests there was a diachoric development of this phenomenon in the wake of the historical events of the early twentieth century, namely World War I (1914-1919), the Russian Revolution (1917-1920), and Roosevelt's New Deal (1930s): "The Bolshevik revolution brought about flourishing of acronyms of the syllabic type (Sovnarkom 'soviet narodnykh komissarov', 'soviet of people's commissar', Sovkhoz 'sovietsko'r'e khoziaistvo', 'soviet agrarian explotation'). Abbreviations like Comintern have been widely accepted around the world, thanks to the influence of the former Communist Party. President Franklin Roosevelt's programs spawned a torrent of “alphabet soup” that named agencies like NRA 'National Recovery Administration' [!]" (267). Rodriguez and Cannon go on to document an "explosive" growth in the use of initialisms and abbreviations around the world after World War II. They then give a very eloquently-presented linguistics of initialisms and abbreviations in English. For a comprehensive answer to your question, I can give you no better than this source, viz.:

> Félix Rodriguez and Garland Cannon, ‘Remarks on the Origin and
>   Evolution of Abbreviations and Acronyms’, in F. Fernández, et al.,
>   eds., English Historical Linguistics 1992: Papers from the 7th
>   International Conference on English Historical Linguistics, Valencia,
>   22-26 September, 1992 (Amsterdam, 1994), pp. 262-72.

I also learned from this source that "sigla" may be another name for the type of constructed therm you're talking about; *sigloe* are "abbreviations formed by initials under new forms" (265).  Another interesting note:
"initials can either become words formed by literation, i.e. receive a letter-by-letter pronunciation (*alphabetisms* or *initialisms*), or else turn into orthoepically pronunced *acronyms*" (266). So it seems, at least according to this source, that the terms you're describing are more properly "acronyms" than "alphabetisms"/"initialisms." (For more notes on this taxonomy, see Algeo, John, 1975, "The acronym and its congeners," in *The First LACUS Forum*, 1974, ed. Adam Makkai and Valerie B. Makkai, pp. 217–234, and López Rúa, Paula 2004 [Acronyms & Co.: A typology of typologies.](https://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/EIUC/article/viewFile/EIUC0404110109A/7911) Estudios Ingleses de la Universidad Complutense 12: 109−129. I have identified these two sources as interesting based on a quick read, but there are potentially lots of others; this seems to be a popular topic in linguistics indeed.)